# WPF dispatcher performance (100-200 updates/sec)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

In a WPF Window, I've got a line chart that plots **real-time data** (Quinn-Curtis RealTime chart for WPF). In short, for each new value, I call a SetCurrentValue(x, y) method, and then the UpdateDraw() method to update the chart.

The data comes in via a TCP connection in **another thread**. Every new value that comes in causes an DataReceived event, and its handler should plot the value to the chart and then update it. Logically, I can't call UpdateDraw() directly, since my chart is in the UI thread which is not the same thread as where the data comes in.

So I call **Dispatcher.Invoke( new Action (UpdateDraw()) )** - and this works fine, well, as long as I update max. 30 times/sec. When updating more often, the Dispatcher can't keep up and the chart updated slower than the data comes in. I tested this using a single-thread situation with simulated data and without the Dispatcher there are no problems.

So, my conclusion is that the **Dispatcher is too slow for this situation**. I actually need to update 100-200 times/sec!

Is there a way to put a turbo on the Dispatcher, or are there other ways to solve this? Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Do you actually need the chart to be updated 100/200 times a second? Or do you simply get 100/200 data packages a second?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but we really need 100 updates/sec. See my comment to your post below.

Comment: What sort of monitor are you using. The vast majority of monitors only update at 60Hz, so there's no point whatsoever in trying to push updates faster than that. As soon as your incoming data rate exceeds the monitor frame rate, your best bet is to batch the incoming data and update the UI once per frame.

Comment: This does seem like quite an unusual request - have you tried running it past Quinn-Curtis themselves? If their charting tool is designed to do > 100Hz UI updates, I suspect they have a sample project doing so. Also, there is an example of their real time charts on the site, which updates from 1Hz to 0.1Hz: http://www.quinn-curtis.com/AspProcessMonitoring.htm

Comment: -1 for not telling us WHY do you want to update chart 100+ times per second. Its deffinitely not good idea to do so from many reasons said in this thread.

Comment: What does 'why' matter. Isn't the entire point of this site to describe technical options? There are lots and lots of questions where the why is disputable, dubious or just totally wrong. That does not however exclude an in this case very well formulated question from deserving an answer. +1 for an original and creative question.

Comment: Except for Pieter, everyone's determined to talk me out of 100Hz updates. Is that a sign of weakness?

Comment: @Pieter: No, I don't think we should limit ourselves to technical solutions. If someone is trying to do something non-obvious and doesn't want to accept the obvious solutions, it is correct to dig deeper, work out what the real problem is.

Comment: @Douglas - Well, yes, you're right about that. However, the comments already mention a dialog that clearly states that a solution limiting the number of refreshes will not suffice. If you see the revisions of my answer, you can even see that the first approach I suggested was exactly such an implementation. However, the OP is very clear in that he wants 100/200 refreshes per second. I dug further, the comments reflect this, so we come to the same conclusion. (BTW: in this instance I see the comments as part of the question.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An option would be to use a shared queue to communicate the data.

Where the data comes on, you push the data to the end of the queue:

```
lock (sharedQueue)
{
    sharedQueue.Enqueue(data);
}
```

On the UI thread, you find a way to read this data, e.g. using a timer:

```
var incomingData = new List<DataObject>();

lock (sharedQueue)
{
    while (sharedQueue.Count > 0)
        incomingData.Add(sharedQueue.Dequeue());
}

// Use the data in the incomingData list to plot.
```

The idea here is that you're not communicating that data is coming in. Because you have a constant stream of data, I suspect that's not a problem. I'm not saying that the exact implementation as give above is the rest, but this is about the general idea.

I'm not sure how you should check for new data, because I do not have enough insight into the details of the application; but this may be a start for you.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not an option. We really need the chart to be updated at least 100 updates/sec. The annoying this is that this works fine in a single thread, as well as in Windows Forms (with multithreading!)

Comment: Tried a different approach. Does this fit your model better?

Comment: Although this might not be the solution I go fore, it at least gives me an option. Using the DispatcherTimer, the chart was refreshed every 10ms. However, I don't like having a timer in my code when it isn't absolutely necessary. I'm now thinking of using the WindowsFormsHost and the "old" Windows Forms chart control, since that one somehow doesn't complain about threads when updating.

Comment: Glad I could at least help you on your way.

Comment: This wouldn't help a single bit as the chart will still only be displayed at your monitor's maximum frequency which is 60 hertz (if you're using a standard flatscreen).

Answer (score 7):

Youre requierments are bonkers- You seriously do NOT need 100-200 updates per second, especialyl as teh screen runs at 60 updates per second normally. People wont see them anyway.

- Enter new data into a queue.
- Trigger a pull event on / for the dispatcher.
- Santize data in the queue (thro out doubles, last valid wins) and put them in.l

30 updates per second are enough - people wont see a difference. I had performacne issues on some financial data under high load with a T&S until I did that - now the graph looks better.

Keep Dispatcher moves as few as you can.

Answer (score 5):

I still like to know why you'd want to update a chart 200 times per second when your monitor can't even display it that fast. (Remember, normal flatscreen monitors have an update-rate of 60 fps)

What's the use of updating something 200 times per second when you can only SEE updates 60 times per second ?
You might as well batch incoming data and update the chart at 60 fps since you won't be able to see the difference anyway.

If it's not just about *displaying* the data but you're doing something else with it - say you are monitoring it to see if it reaches a certain threshold - than I recommend splitting the system in 2 parts : one part monitoring at full speed, the other independently displaying at the maximum speed your monitor can handle : 60 fps.

So please, tell us why you want to update a ui-control more often than it can be displayed to the user.

Answer (score 0):

WPF drawing occurs in a separate thread. Depending on your chart complexity, your PC must have had a mega-descent video card to keep up with 100 frames per second. WPF uses Direct3D to draw everything on screen and optimizing video driver for this has been added in Vista (improved in Windows 7). So, on XP you might have troubles just because of your high data-output rate on poorly designed OS.

Despite all that, I see no reason of printing information to screen with a rate of more than 30-60 frames per second. **Come on!** Even FPS shooters does not require such a strong reflexes from player. Do you want to tell me, that your poor chart does? :) If by this outputting, you produce some side-effects, which are what you actually need, then it's completely different story. Tell us more about the problem then.

Comment: And even if you do somehow manage 100 updates per second, that's of no use whatsoever if your monitor is only refreshing 60 times a second!

Comment: I'm using W7 Pro x64, so poor performance is not due to XP. If you read a little about Quinn Curtis, you'll find out that they've got these real-time chart controls, that only plot the line and don't need a complete redraw for every new value. Quite convenient.

Comment: As I wrote before, I successfully tested this with single-thread WPF as well as Windows Forms. That's why my conclusion is that the problem lies in the Dispatcher.

Comment: Finally, it's not up to you to decide if my application needs 100-200Hz updates. Just take from me that it does. We've done a lot of testing here in the past months and our conclusions are based on test results and 15+ years of experience. The only challenge is that we intent to use WPF for our new application.'

Comment: It's up to the user to decide if application needs 100-200Hz updates. And every user will tell you, that he doesn't need that. Except for, of course, the case when you utilize these 100Hz for something other than human eyes. WPF as I know was not designed to support 1000Hz updates to the screen

Comment: Also the highest documented DAC frequency ever achieved on a production video card for the PC platform is 550 MHz, so you are coming close even to theoretical edge. Ensure your videocard RAMDAC is of sufficient clockrate.

Comment: Funny how all of you focus on me NOT needing 100Hz updates. Only Pieter tries to help me with the problem itself, providing some possible solutions. Thanks Pieter!

Comment: Yea. We all are explaining you how you SHOULD NOT try to eat soup with a fork. We tell "please, take a spoon!". But you don't.

Comment: What we're saying is that it seems like you're trying to find a solution for something that can not be your problem.
There IS NO reason to update a control that fast since you can not display it that fast. And if it is not about displaying but about monitoring the incoming data, you should split the logic from the display.

THAT is what we're telling you.